# import a dbf file in oracle

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-ec2

I have snapshots of two oracle database tablespaces in amazon ec2.
Currently we are able to start a database against one of the tablespaces. Is there any way to import the second tablespace into the oracle with a separate user.

We tried creating a new tablespace pointing at the same dbf file and associate it to a new user but the user does not have any access to any objects. The dbf contents are not loaded into the database.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get there using transportable tablespace.  That said, is there a reason you cannot simply create a new tablespace and then copy the data to the new tablespace?  You could do that either via data pump or SQL.

I am assuming you are more interested in duplicating the data held in that tablespace versus the tablespace itself.

Comment: The way amazon ec2 works we have two different table space set( system.dbf users01.dbf etc) itself present. One for each of the databases i need. The first database is associated with a user by default i want to include the second one too. But am not able to currently.

Comment: I would look at transportable tablespaces then.  It will register the datafiles and tablespaces with the instance and import metadata for object definitions.  This would work for your data tablespaces.  You wouldn't need to have two copies of SYSTEM or other non-data tablespaces, would you?